# The meaning of arrow in an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, notation

I would like to know the interpretation of the following notations in the context of an optimisation problem.

I want to minimize $f_0(\vec{x})$, where the vector $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ is the optimization variable of the problem, and $f_0: \mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is the objective function.

How can I understand this part $f_0: \mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ ?
Does this mean the objective function takes a vector of $n$ dimensional real numbers and gives a single one dimensional real number as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is right, $f_0$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and returns a real number.

$\vec{x}$ is a common notation for vector and sometimes the arrow is being omitted.

Comment: thank you for the clarification :)